# Find a XML node with a specific child using minidom

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I am looking for a way to filter this XML string and print the "identifiant" value where the "source" field is HAL.

```xml
    <sudoc service="idref2source">
        <query>
            <ppn>115565329</ppn>
            <result>
                <source>HAL</source>
                <identifiant>chl</identifiant>
            </result>
        </query>
        <query>
            <ppn>115565329</ppn>
            <result>
                <source>VIAF</source>
                <identifiant>http://viaf.org/viaf/202196105</identifiant>
            </result>
        </query>
    </sudoc>
```

I only parsed the string using minidom

```py
dom = parseString(r.content)
```

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below - 1 line of code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''
 <sudoc service="idref2source">
        <query>
            <ppn>115565329</ppn>
            <result>
                <source>HAL</source>
                <identifiant>chl</identifiant>
            </result>
        </query>
        <query>
            <ppn>115565329</ppn>
            <result>
                <source>VIAF</source>
                <identifiant>http://viaf.org/viaf/202196105</identifiant>
            </result>
        </query>
    </sudoc>
'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
hals = [s.find('identifiant').text for s in root.findall('.//result/[source="HAL"]')]
print(hals)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's [xml](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) module is sufficient for this, in combination with [xpath](https://devhints.io/xpath) - find the element `source`, where the text is "HAL", ping back to the `parent` element and pick out the `identifiant` element within that parent element. Note that here I use `find`, not `findall`, since your question is specifically for the shared xml - if it is a larger file, you can run an iteration using `findall` :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = """[your data above here]"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

root.find(".//source[.='HAL']/..//identifiant").text

'chl'
```